# Looking for a Comparatively Simple Way (without Enumitem) to Not Indent Enumerate Items

Tags: luatex, lists, enumerate, indentation, enumitem

Consider the following simple code which by itself, nicely displays the `enumerate` items without indentation:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item A non-indented enumerate item using enumitem.
\item Another non-indented enumerate item using enumitem.
\item \textbf{Is there an comparatively simple way to do this without invoking the enumitem package?}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

It produces the non-indented output:

[image]

I am presently working on a large document which calls in many packages, not all of which are mutually compatible. Once in a while, I would like to display an enumerate list without indentation. The above code which makes use of  `[leftmargin=*]` immediately after `\begin{enumerate}` nicely accomplishes the task. However, I would like to be able to selectively do the same thing in a comparatively simple fashion without calling in `enumitem`.

QUESTION: What might be the simplest way to selectively display items in an `enumerate` list with no indentation in a long document which is compiled with `lualatex`?

Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to do the calculations `enumitem` does for you yourself. Why can't you just use `enumitem`?